# Type unknown for Data.Element in SwiftUI ForEach using Core Data

Tags: generics, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to use Generics to fetch all items in a Core Data entity. Everything is fine except when inside the ForEach loop.

The type is unknown

in ContentView, I wanna do something like

```
FilteredList<Singer>(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: lastNameFilter)

FilteredList<Baker>(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: lastNameFilter)

FilteredList<Painter>(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: lastNameFilter)    

FilteredList<Friends>(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: lastNameFilter)
```

here is the error

[image]

I can patch it with (entity as! Singer)

[image]

but I loose the power of Generics

This code I'm following and it is from Paul's [Dynamically filtering @FetchRequest with SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui)

and here is the code...

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct FilteredList<T: NSManagedObject, Content: View>: View {

  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

  var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<T>

  var entityItems: FetchedResults<T> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }

  // this is our content closure; we'll call this once for each item in the list
  let content: (T) -> Content

  init(filterKey: String,
       filterValue: String,
       @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {

    fetchRequest =
      FetchRequest<T>(
        entity: T.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K BEGINSWITH %@", filterKey, filterValue))

    self.content = content
  }//init

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(fetchRequest.wrappedValue, id: \.self) { entity in
        //self.content(entity)
        Text("Hello, World! \((entity as! Singer).wrappedFirstName)")
      }//ForEach
        .onDelete(perform: removeAccount)
    }//List
  }//body

  func removeAccount(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
      let oneEntity = entityItems[index]
      moc.delete(oneEntity)
    }//for
    try? moc.save()
  }//removeTransaction
}//FilteredList

struct FilteredList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    FilteredList(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: "A") { (entity: Singer) in
      Text("Hello, World! \(entity.wrappedFirstName)")
    }//FilteredList
  }//previews
}//FilteredList_Previews
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can try is making the `Singer`, `Painter`, `Baker` and `Friend` a type of `Protocol`.

```
extension Singer: PersonProtocol{

}
extension Painter: PersonProtocol{

}
...
protocol PersonProtocol {
    var wrappedFirstName: String? {get set}
    var wrappedLastName: String? {get set}
    ...
}
```

That way when you get to the `ForEach` method you can unwrap the `entity` to `PersonProtocol`

```
    Text("Hello, World! \((entity as! PersonProtocol).wrappedFirstName)")
```

Comment: I tested it and I got rid of the ?, and it works :)

Comment: Great! the ? of course depends on wether the variables are optional in CoreData/Object class.